# has anyone created a docker container using cake?

Tags: docker, cakebuild

Has anyone been able to create a cake.build file that compiles a c# code then creates a docker container? I would like to be able to create a docker file once the base code is built and then run the docker image in a container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build and run Docker images from your Cake scripts using the [Cake.Docker](https://github.com/MihaMarkic/Cake.Docker) community addin.

Add `#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Docker` to the top of your build script and you can then use the `DockerBuild` alias to build your container. You can also optionally use `DockerRun` to run your container.

You can find full documentation on this addin on the website, including for [`DockerBuild`](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerAliases/6AFAC01B) (and [`DockerRun`](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerAliases/74202973)).

---

For example, assuming your `Dockerfile` in a folder called `docker`:

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Docker
// the rest of your build script
Task("Docker-Build")
.Does(() => {
    var settings = new DockerImageBuildSettings { Tag = new[] {"dockerapp:latest" }};
    DockerBuild(settings, "./Docker");
});
```

Comment: Just a quick update for who may copy agc93's snippet, DockerBuildSettings (above) is now DockerImageBuildSettings.

Comment: How to push the docker image to docker hub from cake script?

Comment: @Parthi the Cake.Docker addin also supports aliases for pushing images: [DockerPush](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerAliases/56CBA02D)